# Java library to convert RTF files to PDF.

Tags: java

I have a java desktop service. It currently uses velocity templates to create formatted RTF files. There are quite a few of those templates and changing them (or moving from velocity) is not an option.

I am looking for a quick and easy way to change RTF files to PDF, using java code. I am already checked the following avenues. 
1. iText 
2. OpenOffice
3. JodConverter

However, all of them are PDF creators. I need something that will convert RTF to PDF. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: In the end, a PDF has to be generated. What do you mean by "convert"?

Comment: I meant to say that I do not want to "generate" a PDF from the business logic that is internal to the existing system. I want to "convert" the RTF into PDF, with some code that I could append to whatever I have up and running. If your question is around the fact that ultimately PDF will have to be "created", yes I agree, that is the correct understanding. Hope - the pedantic bit aside - I have been able to communicate the requirement.

Comment: I don't know whether itext still support RTF to PDF, but essentially velocity will give you a writer for RTF document, and you will need a code similar to following to generate (aka convert) PDF: http://cfsearching.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/itext-preview-of-things-to-come-someday.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591239/rtf-to-pdf-in-java

Comment: Open Office and Libre Office (better) will definitely CONVERT RTF to PDF.  They are NOT PDF generators as you have described.  Whether the conversion is suitable/good enough requires testing against your documents.  You can test the conversion-only process with Libre Office and the command line (eg soffice --convert-to pdf  myDocument.rtf)

Answer (score 6):

I have been googling the same question for a long time here is my solution:
Using documents4j and microsoft office 2010 (newer version not tried) (not needed to run in background).
This solution CONVERTS .rtf to .pdf

POM file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-conversion</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-transformer</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Include ALL of them! In .rtf file you need some of them for fonts and stuff like that.
Example of use in java:

```
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 *
 * @author Neon/Jan Madle
 */
public class NewMain {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,             IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"out.rtf"));
    IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
            .baseFolder(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"test"))
            .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
            .convert(in).as(DocumentType.RTF)
            .to(bo).as(DocumentType.PDF)
            .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
            .schedule();
    conversion.get();
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf")) {
        bo.writeTo(outputStream);
    }
    in.close();
    bo.close();
}
}
```

Hope someone finds this usefull!

Answer (score 1):

[JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) helps you to convert RTF files to PDF using Java. Latest version can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/).

As per their website,

> JODConverter, the Java OpenDocument Converter, converts documents between different office formats.
>   It leverages OpenOffice.org, which provides arguably the best import/export filters for OpenDocument and Microsoft Office formats available today.