# PDFBox - embedding RTF content

Tags: java, pdf, rtf, pdfbox

I am creating PDF file using PDFBox from my java code. During that, I need to embed one of the RTF(Rich Text Formate) file in between this new PDF. I cannot find any way to do this by doing google.

I am sure, I cannot write the RTF content being read directly to the PDF.Even though I tried it as below code and it gives me error while opening the PDF. Error says the PDF is corrupted.

**Note:** Similar things can be done in C# and VB, http://www.syncfusion.com/kb/845/how-to-insert-an-rtf-text-into-a-pdf-document. So I am optimistic that there must be something similar in java as well.

I am using PDFBox 1.8.10

**Sample Code:**

```
public static void main(String arg[])  throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    final PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE;
    final int font_size = 8;

    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
    document.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true);
    float x = 10f;
    float y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();  
    float yOffset = 15f;
    float yCurrent = y - yOffset;  

    contents.beginText();
    contents.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, yCurrent);
    contents.setFont(font, font_size);
    contents.drawString("Start Text before RTF"); 
    contents.endText();

    yCurrent = yCurrent - yOffset;

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Test.rtf");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi));
    int c;
    try {
        while((c=br.read()) != -1){
            sb.append((char)c);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    br.close();
    String rtfContent = sb.toString();

    contents.beginText();
    contents.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, yCurrent);
    contents.setFont(font, font_size);
    contents.drawString(rtfContent); 
    contents.endText();
    yCurrent = yCurrent - yOffset;

    contents.beginText();
    contents.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, yCurrent);
    contents.setFont(font, font_size);
    contents.drawString("End Text after RTF"); 
    contents.endText();

    contents.close();


    File file = new File("C:\\pdf\\RTF\\RRFSample1.pdf");
    System.out.println("Sample file saved at : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    document.save(file);
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: :( why -1? help me to improve question if needed.

Comment: I've upvoted this to neutralize it. Somebody is a bit too fast with downvoting, and this isn't the first time. However you have a misconception. RTF is a complex format, and you won't get it drawn just by calling "contents.drawString(rtfContent); ". That synfusion code is a commercial library that likely inteprets the rtf format. Long story short: you can't do this with PDFBox. PDF writing with PDFBox is very low level. Maybe itext can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876678/itext-5-0-0-where-did-rtf-and-html-go http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrtf/

Comment: Thank you Tilman, it helps.

Comment: Though, it is clearly mentioned that using PDFBox, it is not feasible what I need, I am taking a last chance :) . I have converted RTF to PDF using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591666/3808721). And now in memory PDF content in byte array. Is it feasible to append this content in main PDF file that is being generated using PDFBox. Any one has any idea?